# Globally handling exceptions in Web API 2

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to learn and understand global exception handling in Web API 2. When I step through the following code, I thought I'd hit my break point in Handle method but I don't.

What am I missing?

Here's what I've done: I created a new Web API project in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. In my root, I created the following class -- named GlobalExceptionHandler.cs that looks like this:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;

public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
   public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
   {

      // --> Break Point in the next line <--
      string str1 = context.Exception.Message;
   } 
}
```

This is what my Startup.cs looks like:

```
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;

public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
     var config = new HttpConfiguration();

     config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());

     config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

      app.UseWebApi(config);
   }
}
```

When I try to generate an exception in my web api method, I was expecting to hit the Handle method in GlobalExceptionHandler but I'm not.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
   throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
   return Ok("I should not get here because of exception");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WebApi, throwing an HttpResponseException is considered returning a response. It's not considered an unhandled exception, and hence won't get picked up by the exception handler you registered. Try throwing another exception type and it should work.